# How to install Rtools?

Tags: r, rtools

I need to install Rtools in order to work with keras package. I've successfully downloaded Rtools from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/, but then I need to **"put it on a path"**, as it is stated here on this website. I don't understand what is written here about doing that. Could you,please, explain it to me in a simple way and, desirably, with an example?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: See [adobe's guide](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.html) on how to extend the system path on windows machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `path` is the list of all directories the operating system is going to look to find a program when you call it.
An alternative instead of modifying the system path, is to create a file which tells R where to find RTools.
As stated in the installation doc, just open an R console and execute once:

```
writeLines('PATH="${RTOOLS40_HOME}\\usr\\bin;${PATH}"', con = "~/.Renviron")
```

Comment: writeLines('PATH="${RTOOLS40_HOME}\\usr\\bin;${PATH}"', con = "~/.Renviron")

Should I paste it as is? Or should I change anything in this code line?

Comment: just paste it as is, this is the easiest solution I know ;)

Comment: **Now restart R, and verify that make can be found, which should show the path to your Rtools installation.**

When I do this and then (in order to test) paste `Sys.which("make")`
I get only `make ""` .In the example it is shown, that I should get something like ## **"C:\\rtools40\\usr\\bin\\make.exe"**

Comment: Just try if RTools works, for example by compiling code : `Rcpp::cppFunction('int add(int x, int y) { int sum = x + y;return sum;}')`

Comment: Ran this code, got the following:

**There were 12 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
Warning:
In system(cmd) : 'make' not found
Error in sourceCpp(code = code, env = env, rebuild = rebuild, cacheDir = cacheDir,  : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/**

Comment: Looks like RTools was indeed not correctly installed. If you are on Windows, do you confirm you can see `c:\rtools40` directory?

Comment: Yes, I approve having such a directory (C:\rtools40).

Comment: Did you restart R+RStudio?

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+F10 = restarting R, right?
How to restart RStudio?

Comment: just close everything & restart

Comment: Close RStudio itself?

Comment: yes, close RStudio itself

Comment: And what then to do?

Comment: Restart & Try to compile again above code to see if Rtools is now found

Comment: Well, `Rcpp::cppFunction('int add(int x, int y) { int sum = x + y;return sum;}')` compiled, but didn't give any result in console.

Comment: I simply typed `add(1,2)` in console and got **3**. But how  is it related to C++ in R and `cppFunction('int add(int x, int y) { int sum = x + y;return sum;}')`?

Comment: Did you look at the content of what you compiled? You just created your first `add` function in C++, add isn't an R function

Comment: I didn't pay enough attention to it :( . Now I understand.  Thank you very much for your help and effort!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222413/discussion-between-maxim-and-waldi).