# R Package "Maptools" Not Installing With R Version

Tags: r, r-maptools

I was recently trying to install the package entitled, "maptools", as it is essential for my analysis. I tried the following and received this error:

```
install.packages("maptools")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please 
download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/ThisPC/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘maptools’ is not available for this version of R
```

Is anyone familiar with the version of maptools that is compatible with my version of R (version 4.3.3)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: `maptools` has been [archived](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/maptools/index.html) at the request of the authors. This is a long-planned and well thought out deprecation of the package. You can read more about its intentional obsolescence on [its website](http://maptools.r-forge.r-project.org/), where it suggests the use of the `sp` package; many might recommend the `sf` and/or `terra` packages instead of or in addition to that, though that depends heavily on your intended use.

Comment: @r2evans - Ah, so would the sp, sf and/or terra packages be the equivalent of maptools?

Comment: It all depends on what exactly you need, but yes, much (all?) of `maptools` is allegedly supported in `sp`. This has not been a quick operation, so it's referenced in many places. I suggest you start with [`vignette("retiring_rgdal_geos_1", package="sp")`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/vignettes/retiring_rgdal_geos_1.html) and step through the notes there.

Comment: BTW, your question screams that it is a dupe of "Rtools not found" (https://stackoverflow.com/q/53279685/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/77239898/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/a/77994762/3358272) and "package is not available" (https://stackoverflow.com/q/25721884/3358272). I recognize that your underlying issue is that you didn't know that `maptools` has been retired and `sp` should be used, but don't be surprised if the question is closed as a dupe of one or more of the above.